# Syncing BigSQL data with Hive

Tags: hive, bigsql

I want to create a Hive table/view which will be accessing BigSQL (BigInsights 4.2) table. Data will be loaded in BigSQL table and I'm trying to fetch that data from Hive. Is there any procedure to sync data from BigSQL and Hive table?

Answer (score 0):

It will be automatic. the tables already belong to Hive, so when you insert data in a bigSQL Hadoop table you should be able to see it through Hive queries.

The procedure that synchronizes Hive MetaStore and BigSQL is HCAT SYNC , it runs automatically.

```
db2 "call SYSHADOOP.HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS('Schema', 'TableName', 'a', 'REPLACE', 'CONTINUE')"
```

Answer (score 0):

As may be [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCRJT_6.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.bigsql.doc/doc/bigsql_autohivesync.html) :

> Tables that are created under the Hive default schema are not automatically synced; you must synchronize these tables manually if you want them in Db2 Big SQL.

You can invoke the HCAT_SYNC_OBJECTS stored procedure for all current schemas and tables by selecting the Run Metadata Sync service actions menu item.